# How did Boruto learn the shadow clone jutsu?

Tags: boruto

Who taught Boruto the shadow clone Jutsu? In the anime, episode 36 Kakashi asks if Boruto's father (Naruto) taught him the jutsu, but he replied no. If Naruto didn't teach Boruto, then who did?

Comment: According to [Boruto's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki) wiki, it says he self-taught it to himself. Of course it's referencing ep36 and couldn't find anywhere in the episode where Boruto states this

Comment: Yes, he never stated that he self taught himself (if that is even possible - how would he know the hand signs(wouldn't he need at least someone/some instructions)?)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's most likely Konohamaru, as in Boruto the movie, before Sasuke takes Boruto as his pupil, he already knows how to preform that jutsu. And in Boruto episode 36, he states that his father didn't teach him the jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is just my opinion, but I believe that the kids of Boruto's generation are much more talented as compared to people of Naruto's. When Naruto was in the academy, all he had to do was perform Clone technique to graduate. However, with the current generation, everyone already knows the basics. So we can safely assume that nearly everyone knows how to perform the basic shadow clone technique. But Boruto might have seen Naruto perform the Multi-Shadow clone technique (since he uses a lot of them to perform his duties as a Hokage effectively) and would've tried to replicate it on his own.

Comment: `"So we can safely assume that nearly everyone knows how to perform the basic shadow clone technique."` - did you mean **the `non-shadow` clone**, [clone technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Technique)?

Comment: Also, the statement *When Naruto was in the academy, all he had to do was perform Shadow Clone technique* is incorrect. Naruto needed to perform the standard Cloning Technique, not Shadow Clone.

Comment: It's also important to note that the only place that the jutsu is recorded is in the forbidden scroll that Naruto stole, so if Naruto didn't teach Boruto, then someone else must've taught him, or he must've stolen the scroll.